# Finding a list of mutual followers in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a sql query which requires me to generate a list of mutual followers (e.g. A follows B and B follows A)

Our table consists of the FriendshipID, FollowerUserID, FollowingUserID as shown below. Note that FollowerUserID **folllows** FollowingUserID [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqtYF.jpg)

I have tried creating a view table using the code below:

Create view MutualFriends AS 
(select distinct a.FollowerUserID, a.FollowingUserID
    from friendship as a, friendship as b
    where a.FollowerUserID = b.FollowingUserID and a.FollowingUserID = b.FollowerUserID);

However, it returns a repeated view table, e.g. 1 follows 3 is repeated as 3 follow 1.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hr1Je.jpg)

How can we remove the repeated rows in view?

Or are there any other ways to generate the results (without repeating)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do this, using a `LEAST/GREATEST` trick:

```
SELECT
    LEAST(FollowerUserID, FollowingUserID) AS friend1,
    GREATEST(FollowerUserID, FollowingUserID) AS friend2
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT FollowerUserID, FollowingUserID FROM friendship) t
GROUP BY
    friend1,
    friend2
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 2;
```

The subquery aliased as `t` first removes all duplicate follower/following pairs from the original `friendship` table.  This may be necessary if a given one way relationship could appear more than once in the table, e.g. `1 -> 2` appears twice for some reason.

Then, we aggregate by the least of the follower/following and the greatest of the same pair.  If we find that there are two such records, then it implies that the follower and following are mutual.

Comment: Thanks! The code really worked. Before that, I tried putting in distinct using the view table but it didnt work: 
select distinct * from (view_table);

Answer (score 0):

Just agree with solution from @Tim, but I think we don't need to use subquery at "FROM" step (select distinct from friendship....)

```sql
select 
   least(FollowerUserID, FollowingUserID) as u1, 
   greatest(FollowerUserID, FollowingUserID) as u2
from friendship
group by u1,u2
having count(*) = 2
```

Comment: Not necessarily true if a given `u1 -> u2` relationship could appear more than once, see the description in my answer.